# How to delete Jade agents

Tags: java, eclipse, agents-jade, jade4j

I need to run my solution N times and in each iteration a set of agents is created but before passing to the next iteration (i+1), I need to shut down the platform or to delete all the agents so they can be created again in (i+1) iteration.

I have tried the `.dodelete()` and `.kill()` methods but it is not working I guess that I need to shutdown the whole platform each time but I don't know how to do it. Are there any methods or code I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to terminate your Agent.

```
protected void takeDown() {
    // Printout a dismissal message
    System.out.println("Agent-1 "+getAID().getName()+" terminating.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can kill and create your agents with AMS.
[The link to create agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37730416/creata-jade-agent-with-another-agent/44072149#44072149), and use jade.domain.JADEAgentManagement.KillAgent to kill agent.